# unable to use adb with custom Android device

Tags: android, installation, driver, adb

I'm trying to debug an app on a customer-built Android device and I cannot get it connected to ADB. I put the appropriate %SingleAdbInterface% and %CompositeAdbInterface% lines with the hardware IDs in my android-sdk/google-usb_driver/android_winusb.inf (under [Google.NTx86] and [Google.NTamd64]) and I put the VID in username/.android/adb_usb.ini. In my device manager, it says that the drivers are installed (they are located under Android Phone->Android ADB Interface). However, if I run "adb devices" from cygwin, no devices are registered. I've tried killing and restarting ADB, restarting my computer, and updating the driver software to Android Composite ADB Interface to no avail. PDANet was also unable to fix the problem. Any help or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

android_winusb.inf:

```
[Google.NTx86]
;Custom
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1234&PID_5678&REV_9101&MI_00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1234&PID_5678&MI_00
...[other drivers]
[Google.NTamd64]
;Custom
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1234&PID_5678&REV_9101&MI_00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1234&PID_5678&MI_00
```

adb_usb.ini:

```
0x1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `adbd` daemon properly configured and running. You can check if it is running from a terminal emulator on the device.

The person/company which built that "customer-built Android" software should be able to provide more detailed information.